# Proof of Lemma 2.3 p.354 Massey

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> Lemma 2.3: Let $M$ be a an $n-$manifold and $G$ be an abelian group.
>
> (a) For any compact $K \subset M$ and $i > n$ $$H_i(M,M-K;G) = 0$$
>
> (b) If $u \in H_n(M,M-K;G)$ and $\rho_x(u) = 0$ for all $x\in K$, then
> $u=0$.

I'd like to understand the case $4$ of the Lemma, i.e $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $K$ an arbitrary compact.

$\bullet$ We use the following fact which I'm unable to prove: "We assert that for any $u \in H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K)$ exists an open set $N$ containing $K$ and elements $u'\in H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N)$ such that $k_*(u') = u$ where $k$ is the inclusion map.

I do understand the "recall" part of the sentence, but I don't understand how to explicitly write the details.

Let $(X,A) \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K)$ with $v \in H_i(X,A)\subseteq H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,A)\longmapsto u \in H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K)$ under inclusion be given.

What I thought : Since $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$ and both $A,K$ are compact, we have "positive distance". Being $K$ compact, we can choose $N$ as finite union of open balls $B_j$ that cover $K\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n B_j$ such that $B_j \cap A =  \varnothing$ ($N \cap A = \varnothing$).

So in reality $v \in H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus N) \longmapsto u \in H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K)$.

Is this reasoning correct? I'm not sure about last sentence since I think we could have that $v$ has image in $\text{Imm} \mathbb{R}^n \setminus N$.

Comment: I do not understand what you ask. You have an inclusion $j : (X,A) \hookrightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K)$ and it induces $j_*$ on homology groups.

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't understand how to create $N$ properly and verify that satisfies the requests

Comment: You should completely state Massey's Lemma. Not everybody has access to his book. Does he introduce $N$ and what does he claim about it?

Comment: @PaulFrost Am I allowed to cite the words? I think i'm not suppose to scan or add a picture

Comment: In my opinion you are allowed to quote. But perhaps you should ask a question on Meta concerning the rules about quoting resp. embedding scanned parts of books (copyright!). https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes that's probably what I'm goint to do. But I'm goint to edit the post with the statement of the theorem and particular case I'm not able to prove, maybe this particular problem could be solved without adding anything. My curiosity, are you a professor/student or a self-taught?

Comment: I am afraid but I do not yet see what the question is. It seems that you consider some pair $(X,A) \subset (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K)$ with compact $A$ and want to construct some $N$. The essential information is which properties $N$ is required to have. By the way, I am 66 (no longer a student ...) and was active in mathematics many years ago. It is just a hobby now.

Comment: @PaulFrost Edited the post with properties on $N$ and correct typo on $u'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that singular homology has *compact carriers* which means that for each space $X$ and each $x \in H_i(X)$ there exists a compact $C \subset X$ such that $x$ is in the image of the inclusion induced $j_* : H_i(C) \to H_i(X)$ (let me know if you want a proof). The same is of course true for reduced homology groups (which only differ in dimension $0$ from the unreduced groups).

Le $N$ be any set such that $K \subset N \subset \mathbb R^n$. Now consider the long exact sequences of reduced homology groups of the pairs $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N)$.  Since all reduced homology groups of $\mathbb R^n$ are $0$, we get for $i > 0$ commutative squares

$\require{AMScd}$

$$\begin{CD}
H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N) @>\partial>>\tilde H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N)\\
@Vk_*VV@Vj_*VV@.@.\\
H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K) @>\partial>>\tilde H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K)
\end{CD}$$
where the horizontal arrows are isomorphisms and the vertical arrows are inclusion induced. Note that the long exact sequences show that $H_0(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N) = H_0(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K) = 0$, thus your question concerning the existence of $N$ and $u'$ is trivial for $i = 0$ (you may take $N = \mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Thus, given the element $u$, consider $x = \partial(u)$ and find compact $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus K$ and $x' \in H_{i-1}(C)$ such that $j_*(x') = x$. Clearly $N = \mathbb R^n \setminus C$ is an open set containing $K$. By definition $C= \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus N$. Now let $u' = \partial^{-1}(x')$.

Comment: Are you able to show that singular homology has compact carriers? In particular the "b part" of the theorem, i.e that if a homology class is zero under some inclusion of some compact in the space then exist a compact in between the previous two such that the class already was $0$ when included in new compact? Any other answer to my unanswered question is appreciated.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Concerning compact carriers: The image of a singular simplex is a compact subspace of $X$. Thus a singular chain factors through the union of the images of its singular simplices, which is a compact subspace of $X$. For part b one has to know the definition of $\rho_x$. I do not have access to Massey's book.